# What is the distribution for modeling the number of successes in a specific order in N trials?

Tags: distributions, probability, binomial-distribution

The Binomial distribution models the number of successes in N trials, but the successes can be in any order. What's the distribution for when the successes have to be in a specific order? Do you just drop the binomial coefficient?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by successes being "in a specific order"?  On the face of it, outcomes are either successes or not.  All successes are treated interchangeably and likewise all non-successes.  Therefore there is no sense of "order" for either type.

Comment: Suppose H = heads and T= tails and we're flipping coins. I mean the  case where we treat HHT differently from HTH and THH.

Answer (score 3):

The binomial distribution is a *univariate distribution*; the distribution of
$\displaystyle Y=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where  for $1 \leq i \leq N$,
$X_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable indicating success or failure 
on the $i$-th independent trial of the experiment. You are asking about the *multivariate* distribution of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N)$ which is 
$$\begin{align*}
p_{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)&=P\{X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,\ldots,X_N=x_N\}‌​\\&=\prod_{i=1}^NP\{X_i=x_i\} ~~~\text{because the}~X_i~\text{are independent}\\
&=p^k(1-p)^{N-k}
\end{align*}$$
where all the $x_i$ have value $0$ or $1$, and $k$ is the 
number of $x_i$ that happen to have value
$1$, that is, $k$ is the  number of successes on $N$
trials, or, if you like, the *Hamming weight* of the binary
vector $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)$.  So yes, in some sense, you are just 
dropping the binomial coefficient in
$$P\{Y = k\} =  \binom{N}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}.$$
But, the probability mass is not disappearing anywhere; it is just
being *distributed*.
There are $\binom{N}{k}$ length-$N$ binary vectors of Hamming weight $k$
(just choose where the $k$ $1$'s are among the $N$ possible places!) 
each of which gets an equal part $p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$ of the probability
mass $P\{Y = k\}$.  Note that there are a total of
$2^N = \sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}{k}$ points 
$(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)$ on which the probability mass gets distributed as
a result of "dropping" those binomial coefficients.